# Loaded scripts dont work on template loaded by angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Im using the [materialize](http://materializecss.com/) framework to handle my front end ui.

I have a directive which loads a table of data:

*app.blade.php*

```
...
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <employees></employees>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

*app.js*

```
...
app.directive('employees', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'js/templates/employees.html'
  };
});
...
```

inside the employees.html there is a button which is dependent from the materialize.js ([materialize](http://materializecss.com/))

*employees.html*

```
...
<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
<a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- THIS IS NOT WORKING, BUTTON DOES NOT DROP WHEN CLICKED -->
<!-- i think the material js does not reach here -->
...
```

but when i put it inside *app.blade.php* it will work!

*app.blade.php*

```
...
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <employees></employees>
  </div>
</div>
...
...
<!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
<a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- THIS IS WORKING :D -->
...
```

the button is working inside the *app.blade.php* where i have loaded the materialize.js script. but its **not** working inside *employees.html* which was loaded by a directive templateurl.

Comment: This is just a typo in your example code? "</employees>>"

Comment: yes! thank you for correcting, i made the edits now

Comment: can you recreate this issue in a Plnkr?